# Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (PHP incrustado en HTML)

Tags: php, html

Encontré este código de libre uso en Github que funciona bien, devuelve un contador en un `<div>` y los resultados en un `<textarea>`

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $mail = explode('@', $_POST['email']);
    $email = $mail[0];
    $domain = '@'.$mail[1];
    $email = ltrim($email);
    $domain = ltrim($domain);
    $email = rtrim($email);
    $domain = rtrim($domain);
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $domain = stripslashes($domain);
    $email = htmlentities($email);
    $domain = htmlentities($domain);
    $res = addDOT($email);
    echo '<div class="box"><div class="title">Total: '.sizeof($res).'</div><textarea type="text">';
    foreach($res as $mcMails)
    {
        echo nl2br($mcMails.$domain).PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</textarea></div>';
}

function addDOT($str){ 
    if(strlen($str) > 1)
    {
        $ca = preg_split("//",$str); 
        array_shift($ca); 
        array_pop($ca); 
        $head = array_shift($ca); 
        $res = addDOT(join('',$ca)); 
        $result = array(); 
        foreach($res as $val)
        { 
          $result[] = $head . $val; 
          $result[] = $head . '.' .$val; 
        } 
        return $result; 
    } 
    return array($str); 
}
?>
```

Quiero implementarlo incrustado directamente en los elementos HTML de esta forma:

```
<div class="card shadow-sm mx-auto">
  <div class="card-header bg-info justify-content-center">
    <h5 class="card-title text-white">Conteo: <?php echo sizeof($res) ?></h5>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body text-center">
    <div class="position-relative">
      <textarea class="form-control form-control-solid" rows="5" aria-describedby="max"><?php echo nl2br($mcMails.$domain).PHP_EOL; ?></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Y una linea antes coloqué el código PHP que modifiqué para que funcionara incrustado en el HTML:**

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

if (isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $mail = explode('@', $_POST['email']);
    $email = $mail[0];
    $domain = '@' . $mail[1];
    $email = ltrim($email);
    $domain = ltrim($domain);
    $email = rtrim($email);
    $domain = rtrim($domain);
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $domain = stripslashes($domain);
    $email = htmlentities($email);
    $domain = htmlentities($domain);
    $res = addDOT($email);
    foreach ($res as $mcMails);
}

function addDOT($str)
{
    if (strlen($str) > 1)
    {
        $ca = preg_split("//", $str);
        array_shift($ca);
        array_pop($ca);
        $head = array_shift($ca);
        $res = addDOT(join('', $ca));
        $result = array();
        foreach ($res as $val)
        {
            $result[] = $head . $val;
            $result[] = $head . '.' . $val;
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return array(
        $str
    );
}
?>
```

Pero no funciona, obtengo estos errores:

*Notice: Undefined variable: res on line 181*

*Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable on line 181*

**Linea 181:**
`<h5 class="card-title text-white">Conteo: <?php echo sizeof($res) ?></h5>`

*Notice: Undefined variable: mcMails on line 190*

*Notice: Undefined variable: domain on line 190*

**Linea 190:**

```
<textarea class="form-control form-control-solid" rows="5" aria-describedby="max"><?php echo nl2br($mcMails.$domain).PHP_EOL; ?></textarea>
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal? Porqué me sale undefined variable si estoy colocando el código principal antes de donde incrusté los otros?

Comment: Pon el texto con los mensajes de error en vez de una imagen, puedes quitar información que no quieres que sea conocida como la UR u otra. Y dinos a qué líneas corresponde cada mensaje de error. Te dice que tienes variables no definidas y que intentas contar sobre un elemento que no es un array. Pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano listo, una disculpa.

Comment: En ese contexto, `$res` **no es un array**. Debes depurar por qué no lo es. En primer lugar, pon un `var_dump($res);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: ¿En qué parte debo ponerlo? en el código principal me salta los mismos errores si coloco eso

Comment: Pues justo debajo de la línea 181, es sólo para verificar lo que hay en esa variable realmente, luego lo quitarás. El `var_dump` te dirá de qué tipo es `$res` realmente, y qué tamaño y qué contenido tiene, si tuviera algo, o te dirá que es `NULL` o lo que sea. Esto es el ABC de la depuración de código y si aprendes a depurar ahorrarás muchas horas y mucha salud mental. Sí, sí, uno puede pasarse semanas dándole vueltas a algo si no sabe depurar, y muchas veces son errores tontos, otras veces no.

Comment: @A.Cedano obtengo el mismo error: Undefined variable: res, excepto que al final de la linea sale NULL

Comment: Pues eso, pues eso, `$res` es `NULL`. Entonces, ¿por qué es `NULL`? Dado que es indescifrable lo que intentas en tu método `addDOT` (por el nombre, supongo que agregar un punto ¿?), investiga lo que pasa en ese método, pero ante todo depura el parámetro que le pasas a `addDOT`, puede que no haya nada en `$email` o puede que `addDOT` esté mal programado. Todo esto, repito, es el ABC de la depuración: **si algo falla, veríficalo, en el caso de PHP, usando `var_dump`**.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya veo, una disculpa, email es un input donde se coloca un email y la función addDot en efecto le agrega un punto. `<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="ejemplo@gmail.com" autocomplete="off" required>` eso ayuda? Se coloca un email y el código devuelve más correos gmail en base al original, pero con puntos. ejemplo: e.ejemplo@gmail.com

Comment: No sé como depurar ): solo he aprendido un poco de Javascript, HTML y CSS.

Comment: Pues depura `$email`, como ya hiciste con `$res`, es decir, pon un `var_dump($email);`  y dinos qué muestra, y así, con cada cosa que falle, pon `var_dump($laCosaQueFalla);` y revisa qué es esa cosa, de qué tipo, qué extensión, qué estructura, qué contenido.